# Report crashes

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Hi I am trying to have a master detail report. But the report always crashes as i hit the next page on the preview. Both the queries work fine in the query editor.

Main report query

```
select a.Name,a.ftid,a.instno from testschema.ViewA a where a.ftid={?ftid}
```

Shared variables declared in main report separately

```
shared numbervar instno;
instno:={Command.INSTNO}

shared stringVar gnpidesc;
gnpidesc:={Command.Name}
```

Sub report query

```
select a.TOTALAMT,b.Name from  testschema.ViewB a CROSS JOIN testschema.View3 b where a.ftid={?ftid} AND  b.ftid=a.ftid AND  b.instno={?instno} AND a.Name='{?gnpidesc}' ORDER BY a.GENGNPIDESC
```

Shared variables declared inside subreport header separately

```
shared numbervar instno;
shared stringVar gnpidesc;
```

I have delcared 3 parameters fields also with the same name.Sub report only shows for first row in master, if I click next page the application crashes.

Edit
The Sub report contains a cross-tab report in the sub report head section.
Report Layout

```
Main Report
 - Details Section (Main report query)
 - Details Section2 (Sub report)
 - Cross-tab (Sub report Footer- Query 2)
Main Report
```

Comment: can you clarify what "crashes" means - does the report halt with an error message, does the report designer freeze up/disappear, or what?

Comment: Hiya, it says sometimes crw32.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. Sometimes when I hit ctrl-s to save inside crystal reports to save it says 'Unable to Save Data with report. The saved data is incomplete.Generate the data to save? If I click yes the application crashes and exits.

Comment: Uh-oh. All I can suggest is trying to run the report on another machine, and if that crashes then try removing functionality until it stops crashing.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I followed your instructions and found the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certain I've seen this before with my own reports.  You probably have some data quality/consistency issues.

1. Do any of your joining fields have a null value?  All it takes is 1 record ;)
2. Do you have a formulae that references a field with a null value?
3. I don't know what your data source is, but do any of those views have custom formulae that Crystal wouldn't recognize? For example, I often pull data from MS Access queries, but Crystal throws an error if I use the nz() function.
4. One way to find your culprit is to scroll through your preview until you find the page that can't display and crashes.  See what data *would* have displayed on there.

You'll have to either fix the data before it gets to Crystal or rework a function. Good luck.

Comment: thank you I filtered the records from crystal report 'change subrepot links' rather then passing variables to sub report.